# Why is radial ordering necessary?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, conformal-field-theory, commutator, quantization

Suppose I have some conserved charge in a 2 dimensional CFT
$$Q(|z|)=\int_{w=|z|}\text{d}w\,T(w).\tag{1}$$
The infinitesimal transformation induced on a field $\phi$ at $z$ is then
$$[Q(|z|),\phi(z)]=\int_{w=|z|}[T(w),\phi(z)].\tag{2}$$
Books in CFT claim this is not a well defined quantity. On the one hand this seems reasonable to me since at a point in the integral we are taking $[T(z),\phi(z)]$. If $T$ and $\phi$ are distributional one should expect this to run into trouble. On the other hand, in the usual canonical quantization of the scalar field we do not run into such trouble. Indeed, taking
$$H(t)=\int\frac{\text{d}^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^32E_\vec{p}}\,E_\vec{p}a_\vec{p}^\dagger a_\vec{p},\quad\phi(x)=\int\frac{\text{d}^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^32E_\vec{p}}\left(e^{-ipx}a_\vec{p}+e^{ipx}a_\vec{p}^\dagger\right),\tag{3}$$
or
$$H(t)=\int\text{d}^3\,\vec{x}\frac{1}{2}\left(\Pi(t,\vec{x})^2+\vec{\nabla}\phi(t,\vec{x})^2+m^2\phi(t,\vec{x})^2\right)\tag{4}$$
one can easily compute $[H(t),\phi(t,\vec{x})]$. Why don't we see singularities in this case?

Another way of phrasing this would be: in the usual canonical quantization of the scalar field in Minkowki spacetime there is a compatibility between the commutators being taken at equal times and the Hamiltonian being constant in time. In CFT one seems to loose this compatibility at some point in the Euclidean field theory. Namely, while the commutators are taken at equal radius, the conservation equation guarantees that the density is holomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Correlation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function) in 2D CFT are radial ordered for a similar reason that correlation functions in QFT are time-ordered. In fact the radial worldsheet coordinate is often identified with time.
2. Presumably OP's eq. (2) refers to eq. (6.15) in Ref. 1, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405763/2451) related Phys.SE post. That commutator definition only applies to the holomorphic sector of a 2D CFT.
3. It is in principle possible to transcribe the holomorphic/anti-holomorpic variables and [OPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion)s of 2D CFT into real variables. However, the holomorphic/anti-holomorpic formalism is more powerful, as we can rely on [complex function theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis).
4. In contrast, OP's scalar example uses real fields in 3+1D. We do see singularities in equal-time commutators, such as e.g. $[\phi(\vec{x},t),\pi(\vec{y},t)]=i\hbar \delta^3(\vec{x}\!-\!\vec{y})$ in form of a Dirac delta distribution.
   For non-equal times, the singularities can be more complicated.

References:

1. P. Di Francesco, P. Mathieu and D. Senechal, *CFT,* 1997; subsection 6.1.2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 

1. What is the meaning of radially ordering a commutator? Under radial order operators commute.

2. In eq. (2), I was not referring to the equation you mention in Di Francesco et al. (I think since I couldn't find (6.15b)) The integral on the right hand side contains both $0$ and $w$, which is the integral that corresponds to defining $Q$ as the integral over the density at a fixed time slice.

Comment: 4. The commutator in the example I showed suffers of no divergences to my knowledge. I don't see why this have to do with the fact that the fields where real. Several CFTs have real fields. For example a real scalar field in 2d