# Commutators as contour integrals in 2D CFT, and classical limits

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, commutator, poisson-brackets, deformation-quantization

In a 2D CFT, the commutator of two operators

$$A_i=\oint a_i(z)dz$$

can be given by
$$[A_1,A_2]=\oint_0dw\oint_wdza_1(z)a_2(w)$$

where the $z$ integral is taken over a contour around $w$ and the $w$ integral is taken over a contour around the origin, and $a_i(z)$ are holomorphic operators.

What does this look like in the classical limit? When the commutator is replaced with the Poisson bracket $$[\cdot,\cdot]\to i\hbar\{\cdot,\cdot\}.$$
What happens to the integral on the right hand side?

Answer (score 2):

If $$\hat{a}(z)~=~\sum_n z^{-n-h_a}\hat{a}_n
\quad\text{and}\quad
\hat{b}(w)~=~\sum_m w^{-m-h_b}\hat{b}_m,\tag{1}$$
or conversely,
$$ \hat{a}_n~=~\oint_0 \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i}z^{n+h_a-1}\hat{a}(z)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\hat{b}_m~=~\oint_0 \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{2\pi i}w^{m+h_b-1}\hat{b}(w),\tag{2}
$$
then OP is essentially interested in the classical limit $\hbar\to 0$ of the [OPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion) formula
$$ [\hat{a}_n,\hat{b}_m]~=~\oint_0 \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{2\pi i}\oint_w \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i}z^{n+h_a-1} w^{m+h_b-1}{\cal R}\hat{a}(z)\hat{b}(w).\tag{3} $$
Here the symbol ${\cal R}$ denotes radial ordering,
$${\cal R} \hat{a}(z)\hat{b}(w)~:=~\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} \hat{a}(z)\circ\hat{b}(w)&{\rm for}&|z|>|w|, \cr \hat{b}(w)\circ\hat{a}(z)&{\rm for}&|w|>|z|.\end{array}\right. \tag{4}$$
The symbol ${\cal R}$ itself is often implicitly implied in CFT texts. Concerning the proof of the formula (3), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405763/2451) Phys.SE post.

It seems OP is already well aware of the classical limit $\hbar\to 0$ of the commutator on the LHS of eq. (3) in terms of the Poisson bracket, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451) Phys.SE post. Obviously the classical limit $\hbar\to 0$ of the RHS of eq. (3) has to yield precisely the same result.

One idea for further insides is to replace the operators $\hat{a}(z)$, $\hat{b}(w)$ and composition $\circ$ with symbols/functions $a(z)$, $b(w)$ and the [star product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_product) $\star$, and then expand in $\hbar$.