# Notation for current operator in a paper

Tags: quantum-field-theory, notation, regularization

Equation (3) of https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0606800 is the current operator

> $$j_i(x)=e\tilde{\psi}^\dagger(x')v_{x'x}^i\tilde\psi(x)-\frac{e^2}{c}\tilde\psi^\dagger(x')(m^{-1})^{ij}_{x'x}\tilde\psi(x)A_j\tag{3}$$
>   where $x'\rightarrow x$.

What does the $x'\rightarrow x$ mean? Is it some sort of integral transform?

The current $j$ is a function of $x$ and not $x'$. I feel like this is a notation I am unfamiliar with. The same notation is also mentioned in reference 5.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as [point-splitting regularization](https://www.google.com/search?q=point+splitting+regularization), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352146/2451) related Phys.SE post. Concretely, one inserts a $\lim_{x^{\prime}\to x}$ operation on the right-hand side of eq. (3).

Comment: What is the definition of the velocity operator $v_{x'x}$ in terms of a usual velocity operator $v_x$? (same question for mass operator)

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are taking a product of different operators at coinciding points. Typically taking such a product creates a divergence and the the product needs to be regularised. i.e. you need a procedure to tell you how to subtract the divergence. This is covered in most introductory text books on QFT.